# Prevent sending keep alive in httpClient

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, keep-alive

I have a Java/Spring project where I am using httpClient. I wanted to know if it is possible to prevent sending keep alive header. This is how I am creating the client and was wondering if there is a way to disable keep alive

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```

I have this set on Oauth2RestTemplate

the question for which this has been marked as duplicate is not clear to me. It talks about setting it on httpMethod. Where do I get access to httpMethod before I can set the header on it? I have this httpClient that I use to create a HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and set it on RestTemplate and that RestTemplate is used for sending all requests.

Comment: Close httpClient.

Comment: What is the method are you using ?

Comment: Sambit, I saw that link. I am not sure how to get access to that httpMethod before I could try and set requestHeader on it so that it gets applied to the requests

Comment: Implement a  `ConnectionReuseStrategy` with a keepAlive() method that simply returns false.   You can also pass this to setConnectionReuseStrategy in HttpClientBuilder.  The answer provided in the duplicate link seems outdated.